# react getting an unauthorized-401 error every first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-saga

I get a 401 error on any request, but as soon as I refresh the page, the problem is solved, I do not know what is the reason for that

I use react saga

The token is fetched and placed in the storage properly, but the problem is that it is not injected into the header request the first time.

I need to reload the page again and then everything works fine

**this axios**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { api } from "../config";


// default
axios.defaults.baseURL = api.API_URL;


// content type

const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('authUser'))
  ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('authUser')).data.token : null;
 
if (token) axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;

// content type
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
// intercepting to capture errors
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    return response ? response.data : response;
  },
  function (error) {

    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    let message;
    switch (error.response.status) {

      case 500:
        message = "Internal Server Error";
        break;
      case 401:
      window.location.href = '/login';
        message =  "not";
        break;
      case 404:
        message = "Sorry! the data you are looking for could not be found";
        break;
      default:
        message = error.response.data.message
        ;
    }
    return Promise.reject(message);
  }
);

/**
 * Sets the default authorization
 * @param {*} token
 */
const setAuthorization = (token) => {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
};

class APIClient {
  /**
   * Fetches data from given url
   */

  //  get = (url, params) => {
  //   return axios.get(url, params);
  // };
  get = (url, params) => {
    let response;

    let paramKeys = [];

    if (params) {
      Object.keys(params).map((key) => {
        paramKeys.push(key + "=" + params[key]);
        return paramKeys;
      });

      const queryString =
        paramKeys && paramKeys.length ? paramKeys.join("&") : "";
      response = axios.get(`${url}?${queryString}`, params);
    } else {
      response = axios.get(`${url}`, params);
    }

    return response;
  };
  /**
   * post given data to url
   */
  create = (url, data) => {
    return axios.post(url, data);
  };
  /**
   * Updates data
   */
  update = (url, data) => {
    return axios.patch(url, data);
  };

  put = (url, data) => {
    return axios.put(url, data);
  };
  /**
   * Delete
   */
  delete = (url, config) => {
    return axios.delete(url, { ...config });
  };
}
const getLoggedinUser = () => {
  const user = sessionStorage.getItem("authUser");
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return JSON.parse(user);
  }
};

export { APIClient, setAuthorization, getLoggedinUser };
```

**this login saga**

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";

// Login Redux States
import { LOGIN_USER, LOGOUT_USER, SOCIAL_LOGIN } from "./actionTypes";
import { apiError, loginSuccess, logoutUserSuccess } from "./actions";

//Include Both Helper File with needed methods
import { getFirebaseBackend } from "../../../helpers/firebase_helper";
import {
  postJwtLogout,
  postJwtLogin,
  postSocialLogin,
} from "../../../helpers/backend_helper";


import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';



const fireBaseBackend = getFirebaseBackend();

function* loginUser({ payload: { user, history } }) {
  try {
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULTAUTH === "firebase") {
      const response = yield call(
        fireBaseBackend.loginUser,
        user.email,
        user.password
      );
      yield put(loginSuccess(response));

    } else if (process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULTAUTH === "jwt") {
      const response = yield call(postJwtLogin, {
        username: user.email,
        password: user.password,
      });

      sessionStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(response));
      if (response.status === "SUCCESS") {

        yield put(loginSuccess(response));
        history.push("/dashboard");
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        yield put(apiError(response));
       
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(apiError(error));
    toast.error(error, { autoClose: 6000 });
  }
}
function* logoutUser() {
  try {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("authUser");
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULTAUTH === "jwt") {
      const response = yield call(postJwtLogout);
      yield put(logoutUserSuccess(LOGOUT_USER, response));
    } else {
      yield put(logoutUserSuccess(LOGOUT_USER, true));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(apiError(LOGOUT_USER, error));
  }
}

function* socialLogin({ payload: { data, history, type } }) {
  try {
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULTAUTH === "firebase") {
      const fireBaseBackend = getFirebaseBackend();
      const response = yield call(fireBaseBackend.socialLoginUser, data, type);
      sessionStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(response));
      yield put(loginSuccess(response));
    } else {
      const response = yield call(postSocialLogin, data);
      sessionStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(response));
      yield put(loginSuccess(response));
    }
    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(apiError(error));
  }
}

function* authSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(LOGIN_USER, loginUser);
  yield takeLatest(SOCIAL_LOGIN, socialLogin);
  yield takeEvery(LOGOUT_USER, logoutUser);
}

export default authSaga;
```

Comment: Did you try it in `incognito` mode?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I always use private browsing and do not use anything else

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I have provided and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: DreamBold It's not about firebase
I just use jwt to login
And I can delete it from all the apps if that's the problem